# pattern matching in the filename and change extension - bash script

Tags: bash, grep, pattern-matching

I want to use name-last.txt files to call another several files in previous directories which names belong to the filename string:

For example, for Perez-Castillo.txt, I want to used: (1) grep in Perez-Castillo.txt, (2) grep in Perez.list and (3) grep in Castillo.list.

I have this part:

```
    for i in *.txt; 
    do 
        wc -l $i > out1.txt
        grep -c "something" ../${i%-*}.list > out2.txt
        grep -c "something" ../${i#*-}.list > out3.txt
    done;
```

However, I fail to call i.e **Castillo.list**, as my script is calling **Castillo.txt.list**

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Bash doesn't let you nest two transformations into a single parameter expansion, so there is no way to delete both a prefix and a suffix with a parameter expansion.

So the simplest approach is to just remove the `.txt` extension at the beginning:

```
for i in *.txt; do
    pfx=${i%.txt}
    wc -l "${pfx}.txt" > out1.txt
    grep -c "something" "../${pfx%-*}.list" > out2.txt
    grep -c "something" "../${pfx#*-}.list" > out3.txt
done;
```